# 2d array passing in java

Tags: java, arrays

Class file:I use 2d int array to store the value then i set the setter and getter

```
public class SquareMatrix implements SquareMatrixInterface{
    int[][] squareMatrix; 

    public int[][] getSquareMatrix() {
        return squareMatrix;
    }

    public void setSquareMatrix(int[][] squareMatrix) {
        this.squareMatrix = squareMatrix;
    }
}
```

Interface file

```
public interface SquareMatrixInterface {
    public int[][] getSquareMatrix();
    public void setSquareMatrix(int[][] squareMatrix);
}
```

Main: I put a value and try to set the value to the setter but it gives me error

```
public class test {

    SquareMatrixInterface matrixA = new SquareMatrix();
    SquareMatrixInterface matrixB = new SquareMatrix();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] m1 = {{1,2},{3,4}};
        matrixA.setSquareMatrix(m1);

    }
}
```

why it give me error when i try to pass in the array to the setter
how to pass a 2d array without include java library

Comment: You already have a correct answer (about static vs nonstatic), but next time please tell us an exact error message and stacktrace.

Comment: can you include the stack trace

Answer (score 3):

you cant access **non static** properties inside **static** block.. [Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field] so you need to rewrite your main method to..

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SquareMatrixInterface matrixA = new SquareMatrix();
        int[][] m1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
        matrixA.setSquareMatrix(m1);
    }
```

**OR**

```
static SquareMatrixInterface matrixA = new SquareMatrix();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] m1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    matrixA.setSquareMatrix(m1);
}
```